# Mac Terminal - How to get rid of the notifications "Bash Alias not found" when opening the terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, alias

While following multiple tutorials on some php frameworks I entered some commands in the terminal not really understanding what I was doing (creating aliases mainly...). 
My problem is that when I start my terminal now I have some wierd things written and I do not have a single clue how to get those away. I know it is very vague but when trying to search in other posts, on internet and so forth and did not found or understud anything. Hope someone can help me moving forward. Thank you in advance.

```
Last login: Tue Dec 11 12:35:38 on ttys000
-bash: alias: -c: not found
-bash: alias: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini: not foun
-bash: alias: -c: not found
-bash: alias: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini: not found
-bash: alias: -c: not found
-bash: alias: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini: not found
macbook-pro-de-my-name:~ someFolder$
```

Comment: Have a look at your `~/.profile`. Looks like there are some misconfigurations.

Comment: Do you see a `~/.bashrc` oder `~/.bash_aliases` or something like that?

Comment: Thank you very much alex. I checked on internet and fond a script for automator to show hidden files. So after running it I managed to open .profile as you suggested and deleted all the content of that file. It solved my problem. If you post your suggestion as answer I will accept it. Thank you again :)

Comment: Deleting all contents it not the way to go... You should only delete what's making problems. :-/

Comment: Of course. There was only 3 lines all related to the alias of /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini that is why I deleted all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you installed MAMP in history. Because of this you `.profile` was changed by MAMPs installation. Probably you un-installed MAMP after that but your `.profile` is still the same as after the installation. So you should delete the lines which are making problems.

For editing `.profile` just type `open -a TextEdit ~/.profile` into your Terminal.

Comment: Deleting the lines related to error notifications in ~/.profile as you suggested it made the trick... Thanks again :)